# Can't resolve package dependencies when building ros for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: rosdep, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I read ros will be officially available for Ubuntu 16.04 in July, so I tried to build it from source as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source). Unfortunately it can't resolve some package dependencies:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws » rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade -y                                                                                                  
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
image_geometry: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [xenial]
python_qt_binding: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS version [xenial]
rqt_pose_view: No definition of [python-qt-bindings-gl] for OS version [xenial]
rqt_plot: No definition of [python-qt-bindings-qwt5] for OS version [xenial]
qt_gui: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS version [xenial]
cv_bridge: No definition of [libopencv-dev] for OS version [xenial]
```

I tried to resolve those dependencies by myself and installed **libopencv-dev** and **python-qt-binding** through *apt-get*. This did not change anything. What should I do now?

**EDIT:**
There are dependencies missing to install ros under Ubuntu 16.04. Those dependencies, like pcl, need to be, too. If it is not too urgent to use ros under Ubuntu 16.04, I would recommend to wait until July, for when the official release for Ubuntu 16.04 is announced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232795/can%27t-resolve-package-dependencies-when-building-ros-for-ubuntu-16.04/) by [Jonas25](https://answers.ros.org/users/26658/jonas25/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason you get this error is because for the *system dependencies* that are mentioned in your error message, `rosdep` doesn't have any *rules* that allow it to map these 'generic' names to Xenial-specific debian package names (see [Why rosdep instead of others?](http://answers.ros.org/question/215059)).

> I tried to resolve those dependencies by myself and installed `libopencv-dev` and `python-qt-binding` through `apt-get`. This did not change anything.

And that is expected (as I hope you understand now), as installing these manually doesn't change the fact that `rosdep` doesn't know about them (on Xenial, that is). See [rosdep/base.yaml :: libopencv-dev](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/88c5d1ed3ceb16bb16aa91dc246a5a701907be5d/rosdep/base.yaml#L1916-L1926) for the current rule set for `libopencv-dev` for instance: note it's missing a `xenial` key.

> What should I do now?

You have a couple of options:

1. wait for the rules to be updated and Xenial keys to be added: note that this also requires those packages to actually have Xenial releases.
2. contribute the missing rules yourself: see [Contributing rosdep rules](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) for that.
3. make `rosdep` resolve dependencies for Wily (or an even older release) instead: this will require those packages to exist -- and with the *same name* -- on Xenial, which may or may not work. Append `--os=ubunty:wily` to your `rosdep` invocation.

**Note**: this is a work-around, and you should only use this when trying to deal with unsupported platforms (such as Ubuntu derivatives being identified as an unknown OS, or unsupported releases of distributions).

1. ask `rosdep` to ignore the missing dependencies and continue with whatever it does know about: you'll have to make sure you have those dependencies installed, as otherwise you'll run into issues while configuring / compiling, but it would let you continue. Append `-r` to your `rosdep` invocation.

See [rosdep command reference - options](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/commands.html#options) for more information on the various `rosdep` command line options.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jonas25](https://answers.ros.org/users/26658/jonas25/) on 2016-04-25**:
I worked through the missing dependencies by installing their equivalent at Ubuntu 14.04, as written on this website: http://rosindex.github.io/deps/. Trying your fourth step the only error I got was gazebo5 is missing now. Trying to solve that, as the current version is gazebo7...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-25**:\

> I worked through the missing dependencies by installing their equivalent at Ubuntu 14.04

Manually, or by running `rosdep` with the `--os=ubuntu:trusty` switch?

> Trying your fourth step the only error I got was gazebo5 is missing now

If you don't need gazebo, you can probably just skip it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-25**:\

> Trying your fourth step [..]

Note that these weren't necessarily steps, but more various different options that should lead to the same goal: allowing you to install / build ROS on a currently unsupported platform.

**Comment by [Jonas25](https://answers.ros.org/users/26658/jonas25/) on 2016-04-25**:
I installed the dependencies manually, although I think using `--os=ubuntu:trusty` would have had the same effect. And I wanted to write "option" instead of "step". It is currently compiling. Big thanks for your help, it made some things clear to me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-25**:\

> I installed the dependencies manually [..]

It would be *really* nice if you could contribute rules for the packages that you've verified you could install under Xenial. I don't know how many are missing currently, but it would help getting Kinetic on Xenial as well.

**Comment by [Jonas25](https://answers.ros.org/users/26658/jonas25/) on 2016-04-25**:
The building process stopped due to some problems with the pcl libraries. I added the repository but it does not support Ubuntu 16.04 yet. Do you know a workaround for this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-25**:
You'll probably have to build that from source as well. Can't help you with that I'm afraid, never done it myself.

**Comment by [Jonas25](https://answers.ros.org/users/26658/jonas25/) on 2016-04-25**:
You are right, and I tried this, but to build this there are again dependencies missing. Thus, I gave up now, as it is no more worth the work. Still thank you a lot!